# Laravel relationship Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a relationship between a user and a appointment.

This is the user model

```
public function session(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
    }
```

This is the session model

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In my controller I attempt to call it like so

```
User::find(1)->session()->count();
```

But i get this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Session()

Comment: try `$user = User::withCount('session')->find(1);` and then `echo $user->session_count`

Comment: add **counsellingSessions** method content

Comment: then try `User::find(1)->session->count();`

Comment: What's the result of `dd(get_class_methods(User::find(1)));`?

Answer (score 0):

don't use **session** for function just create model **UserSession** and function also like below

```
public function userSession(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\UserSession');
}
```